# Encoding 10-bit data on 2 8-bit analog channels

Tags: analog, pwm, encoding

I have some (expensive) weird real time hardware with only two 12-bit ADC inputs vacant, and it needs to read 10-bit samples taken by a MCU with 8-bit PWM output ports. The ADC can take samples at around 100Hz, the PWM operates at 32KHz, and I want samples from my sensor at at least 10Hz (more is better).

I'm planning on encoding 5 bits on each analog channel by hooking the PWM outputs to RC filters, but this seems dangerous in many ways: I can't really guarantee the PWM high/low levels, and when the 5 low bits overflow I'll have a weird discontinuity. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Solutions:

- Use a micro with more PWM bits (many have 16-32 bit PWM)
- Use a 10 bit separate DAC to generate your 10 bit value.
- Dither the 8-bit PWM in software (by adjusting the PWM value on each cycle) to increase resolution.
- Use 4x 8-bit channels in parallel, averaged with resistors.

Comment: The problem is, the MCU is an arduino running some libraries I don't control, so I cannot change the PWM duty cycle at regular intervals or meddle with the interrupts

Comment: Do you have source code for your arduino?

Comment: I can find it, but I'd rather not meddle with it too much to avoid breaking stuff. If it comes down to this, I'll probably do the 5-bit per channel thing.

Comment: Arduino has 16 bit timer you know? It could output your PWM value directly...